# modify dictionary using dictionary comprehensions without creating a new dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the below dictionary:

```
d = {'lnsd-02': 'manager', 'lnsd-03': 'manager', 'lnsd-01': 'quorum', 'lnsd-04': 'manager', 'lnsd-05': 'manager'}
```

I am trying out dictionary comprehensions on similar lines of list comprehensions.

```
for i in d:
    if i[-2:] in ('02', '05'):
            d[i]='quorum-manager'
```

How do i apply dictionary comprehension to the above code and change values for certain keys  without creating a new dictionary ?
something like below

```
d[i] = {i: 'quorum-manager' for i in d if i[-2:] in ('02', '05')}
```

finally, i need the original dictionary with values changed as

```
d = {'lnsd-02': 'quorum-manager', 'lnsd-03': 'manager', 'lnsd-01': 'quorum', 'lnsd-04': 'manager', 'lnsd-05': 'quorum-manager'}
```

Comment: Why do you want to use a dictionary comprehension? I would just use a `for` loop - the whole point of a dict or list comprehension is to generate a new dict or list, and you don't want to just use them for side effects.

Comment: A dictionary comprehension always **creates a new dictionary** unless an exception is thrown in it.

Comment: List comprehensions are just a fancy syntax to avoid having to say `new_list = []; for ...: new_list.append(thing)` which looks slightly uglier. Same for dictionary comprehensions. Don't fuss over writing a for loop, it's basically the same.

Comment: @DonkeyKong i am happy using the for loop. the only reason i want to use dict comprehension is to save some space/lines in code. i have mulitple instances where i need to do something similar

Comment: I've timed the for loop and the accepted answer. On my notebook the latter is 34÷39% slower  than the for loop  This is not to criticize the accepted answer but to question your question...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [`dict.update`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) method:

```
d.update({i: 'quorum-manager' for i in d if i[-2:] in ('02', '05')})
```

The *comprehension* will create a new dictionary, but this dictionary will only be used to *update the contents* of your original dictionary `d`.

---

Given your original data:

```
>>> d = {'lnsd-02': 'manager', 'lnsd-03': 'manager', 
    'lnsd-01': 'quorum', 'lnsd-04': 'manager', 'lnsd-05': 'manager'}
```

And applying

```
>>> d.update({i: 'quorum-manager' for i in d if i[-2:] in ('02', '05')})
```

The result is

```
{'lnsd-04': 'manager', 'lnsd-03': 'manager', 'lnsd-01': 'quorum', 
'lnsd-05': 'quorum-manager', 'lnsd-02': 'quorum-manager'}
```

Which matches your desired result